# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i'm trying to execute this PL or query below bt got this error:

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;   The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue

- here is the code:

```
DECLARE 
v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR; 
faID varchar(12);
despriction varchar(50);
currency varchar(3);
amount number ;
startD varchar(8);
endD varchar(8);
loID varchar (12);
Unit varchar(50);
begin 

TM_MAIN('B','00024657', v_cursor);
 
LOOP 
FETCH v_cursor 
INTO facility_ID,despriction, currency , amount , startD, endD ,loId, Unit; 
EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND; 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(faID ||  ' | ' || despriction || '  ' || currency || '  ' || amount || ' ' || startD || ' ' || endD || ' ' || loId || ' | ' || glUnit );

END LOOP; 
CLOSE v_cursor; 
END;
```

Comment: That code looks OK. Where did you execute it?

Comment: try to add a slash `/` on the separate line in the end

Answer (score 0):

Looking at code I can see that you declare faID varchar(12) but trying to fetch cursor in facility_ID